# Eclipse Hangs on importing preference file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, preferences

When I am trying to import the exported file using `IPreferenceService.importPreferences(InputStream);` then the eclipse just hangs and i need to kill it. It doesn't even throws any error log. How to resolve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could try to split-up `importPreferences` by calling `readPreferences(InputStream)`, followed by `applyPreferences(outputFromReadPreferences)` to see at which step it actually fails.

Comment: Thanks KompjoeFriek, I did try `readPreferences` and `applyPreferences`. Read is working fine. But apply doesnt. For apply preferences, we need `IExportedPreferences` object. I tried creating  as `IExportedPreferences prefs = IPreferencesService.readPreferences(InputStream). And here it is giving CoreException: Problems importing preferences.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason. So I am posting the finding, it might be helpful for someone who also faces the same issue.

I was importing the preferences during the startup of eclipse, due to which it was hanging.
If we debug it, it was importing all the preferences but on simple run, it was hanging.
So I changed the import preference after eclipse startup and it worked.